# Laravel Factory - generate fake json array data with random amount of iterations in a single column

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

In **ListingFactory.php** I have something like this

```
return [
    'reviews' => json_encode([
        'user' => fake()->name(),
        'body' => fake()->paragraph(),
    ]),
]
```

Additionally, in the **DatabaseSeeder.php** I have this at the moment

```
\App\Models\Listing::factory(10)->create();
```

The current problem is that it will always generate one instance of review. What I want is a random number of reviews in a range.

For example, right now the table column of **Review** will always be `[{}]`, I want something like `[{}, {}, {}]` or `[]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't make it complicated. Just generate a random number and then generate that many reviews.

```
$reviews = [];
$amount = rand(1,10);

for($x = 0; $x < $amount; $x++ ){
   $reviews[] = [
        'user' => fake()->name(),
        'body' => fake()->paragraph(),
    ];
}


return [
    "reviews" => json_encode($reviews),
];
```

Answer (score 1):

According to laravel 10 docs,
https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-factories#instantiating-models

If you already have a **Factory** defined for your **Model** then,
you can use

```
Model::factory(count)->make()
```

to generate fake data without persisting the data into the database.

Answer (score 0):

I would believe that `randomElements()` can do what you want, it takes `x` elements from a sequence. Combine that with a random number and you would achieve that.

```
json_encode(fake()->randomElements(
    [
        [
            'user' => fake()->name(),
            'body' => fake()->paragraph(),
        ],
        [
            'user' => fake()->name(),
            'body' => fake()->paragraph(),
        ],
        [
            'user' => fake()->name(),
            'body' => fake()->paragraph(),
        ],
    ],
    random_int(1, 3),
)),
```

If you would change the amount of reviews, increase random_int(1, 10) for a sequence of 10.

Answer (score 0):

Simply generate your fake data in loop.

```
$reviews = [];

foreach(range(1,10) as $i) { // f.e. run it 10 times
  $reviews[] = [
     'user' => fake()->name(),
     'body' => fake()->paragraph(),
  ]
}

return [
      "reviews" => json_encode($reviews),
 ]
```